# importing csv file into mysql using R

Tags: mysql, r, csv, rstudio

I'm a newbie (student) and I'm having an issue importing a CSV file into a MySQL database using RStudio.

Here is my syntax:

```
dbSendQuery (mydb, "LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/path/to/file/test.csv'
             INTO TABLE NameOfTable
             FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
             ENCLOSED BY '"'
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
             IGNORE 1 LINES;")
```

Now I've tested that query in MySQL and it works just fine, but when I try and run it in R, it gives me the following error:

> Error: unexpected string constant in:
>
> "ENCLOSED BY '"'
>
> LINES TERMINATED BY '"
>
> IGNORE 1 LINES")
>
> Error: unexpected numeric constant in "             IGNORE 1"

Also, I've connected to my database and am able to see my tables through R so my connection shouldn't be the problem. Any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: You'll need to escape the `"` so that it doesn't end your string: `ENCLOSED BY '\"'`.

Comment: thanks so much! that worked perfectly!!